# Change color ohmyzsh with the theme of agnoster

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2, zshrc

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the image I would like to change the colors, for example that blue is too dark.

[image]
[image]

but if I change the theme colors this setting changes the colors.

Is there anything I need to set up in some configuration file?

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using iTerm, since you have Smooth and Solarized Dark, and also according to selected topic tags. So, in that case scenario most of the colors can be changed here:
iTerm -> Settings -> Profiles -> [ choose needed profile ] -> Colors.

Some colors can be configured additionally, but it depends on iTerm theme used.